# Using Groovy's JSONBuilder method triggers StackOverflowError

Tags: json, groovy

I believe we're running into a similar bug as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8916 and if possible to confirm my theory, the issue occurred within Groovy version 2.4.21 but not 2.4.12.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

    void update(Map request, String env=null, String apiUrl=null, String credentialsId=null){
        env = env ? env : getAthenaEnv()
        apiUrl = apiUrl ? apiUrl : (props.athena.apiUrl ?:  props.athena[env].apiUrl)
        credentialsId = credentialsId ? credentialsId : (props.athena.credentialsId ?: props.athena[env].credentialsId)

        print "Updating athena record for ${request.appName} in ${env} environment"
        request = replaceNull(request)
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: credentialsId, variable: 'apikey')]) {
            
            def requestData = new JsonBuilder(request).toString()
           
            def sanitizer = load "src/utils/SanitizerUtil.groovy"
            def projectName = sanitizer.sanitize(request.appName)
            def requestUrl = "${apiUrl}/applications/${projectName}"
            print "requestData: ${requestData}"

            def response = httpRequest url: requestUrl,
                    customHeaders:  [[name: 'apikey', value: apikey]],
                    httpMode: 'PUT',
                    contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
                    requestBody: requestData,
                    validResponseCodes: '200,404'

            print "response.status: ${response.status}"
        }
    }
```

```
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z] java.lang.StackOverflowError
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at org.codehaus.groovy.util.AbstractConcurrentMap.getOrPut(AbstractConcurrentMap.java:37)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValuePreJava7.get(GroovyClassValuePreJava7.java:96)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getClassInfo(ClassInfo.java:172)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:281)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:901)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.getMetaPropertyValues(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:450)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.getProperties(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:469)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at groovy.json.JsonOutput.getObjectProperties(JsonOutput.java:338)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:331)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:469)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:332)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:469)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:332)
[2023-05-09T22:03:55.095Z]  at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:469)
```

Is it possible to confirm the following, would I be required to upgrade to Groovy 2.5 and use JsonGenerator instead of JsonBuilder based on Jira ticket

Answer (score 0):

Workaround / Solution

The JsonBuilder StackOverflowError is related to the actual json object not  formatted correctly, we removed `.toString()` when calling JsonBuilder.

```
//Original
def requestData = new JsonBuilder(request).toString()

//Change 
def requestData = new JsonBuilder(request)
```